# PHP: Unable to execute command line script from Web

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, shell-exec

I am on EC2 and logged in with `ec2-user`.I am using following script to execute a Python script from Apache. IT works from command line but not from web and does not print any output at all. The code is below:

```
<?php

$command = escapeshellcmd('python3 /home/ec2-user/f1/f2/file.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;

?>
```

Same script works fine from command line

Comment: Guess #1: Usually the (system-) user that runs a webserver and thus executes PHP in a web-context differs from the user you are using when connecting to a server using SSH. In that case `python3` might not be available in the `PATH`.

Comment: Guess #2: On some webservers (I don't know about the Amazon services) some PHP functions such as `shell_exec` might be [disabled in the php.ini (setting `disable_functions`)](http://php.net/manual/de/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) for security reasons. Please also rerer to: [“Dangerous PHP Functions Must be Disabled”](https://www.eukhost.com/blog/webhosting/dangerous-php-functions-must-be-disabled/)

Comment: @feeela `disable_functions` has no value set at all. I also set full path of Python3 yet no output

Comment: The owner of your Php file and the user under which Apache is running should have permission to run the python script

Answer (score 0):

Ssh the server and execute this command:

```
which python3
```

It will show you some path so update your command like this:

```
path/to/python3 /home/ec2-user/f1/f2/file.py
```

Comment: this python3 /home/ec2-user/f1/f2/file.py is working fine when you execute it via command line"? what's the output?

Comment: yes it works fine from CLI. it gives desired output. From Web it outputs nothing.